# Adding a delay to a css menu (still supporting non-js browsers)

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a three level menu that works on :hover and uses only css. Now I need to add a small delay to the hovers (changing therefore my css :hovers to a .hover class and using jQuery). Problem is, if a browsers has javascript turned off, will the menu will still work? Can I have both 'systems' working at the same time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class `no-js` on your `<html>` tag:

```
<html class="no-js">
```

Then remove that class from JavaScript:

```
$('html').removeClass('no-js');
```

And in CSS you target browsers with JS disabled like so:

```
.menu.hover { color: red; } // .hover class
.no-js .menu:hover { color: red; } // pseudo :hover JS disabled
```